# JQUERY Geocoding within a form & transferring latlng as well as other stuff to PHP

Tags: jquery, forms, google-maps-api-3

HI there & thanks for reading me through...
I have serached the &A & ttweaked with JQUERY & the gocoding from GoogleMpasV3, but don't seem to put all together. Here 's what I'm trying to do :
I have a simple form  which would be passing along some additionnal data together with lat & lng found using the Googlemaps V3 geocoder -. The adresse to be geocoded would be entered by the user within the form , geocoded, and the hidden lat & lng inputs filled with the relevant values...

I got the part where the hidden inputs are filled within a form but when I add some other data & try to submit the form using either a button or the "submit" type input, i get stuck:

Here is my basic form layout :

```
<form methot="post action="some.php">
<input type="hidden" id="param1" name="param1" value="value1">
<input type="text" id="adress" name="address">
<input type="button" id="geocodeBtn" name="geocodeBtn" Value="GeoCode!">
<input type="button" id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" value="Done!">
</form>
```

I understand that I could either use an onclick event the javascript way on the 'geocode Btn', or use a JQUERY ('#geocodeBtn').on.('click', function(...) but either way I can't make the geocoding work AND submit the data upon submission...

Would someone be kind enough to pave the way for me. I realize that this is easy JQUERY / JS stuff but I get confused & am getting nowhere..
Many thanks,
JM

Answer (score 0):

Kinda makes more sense to do it a different way - just have the one button 'submit', remove your geocode button.
When someone submits, post all the data to PHP and you can do a curl function to geocode from that PHP file.

This is better as it prevents people from changing their lat & lng values after the geocode.

Example curl to get lat & lng from google:

```
function getLocGoogle($addr){
$loc=array();
$addr=urlencode($addr);
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$addr&sensor=false";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response = json_decode($response);
if($response->status=='OK'){
    $loc['lat'] = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $loc['lon'] = $response->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

    return $loc;
}
return false;
```

}

Comment: Jacobs
Thanks a lot. I understand the logic:the geocoding would be done once the address is posted...
I would then be able to position the address w/ marker on a map so that the user could fine tune the placement of the marker using a draggable marker.. great stuff !!
Many thanks!
I'll post the entire PHP/Map & draggable marker / marker fine-tuning stuff once done for anyone interested ... My humble contribution !